# Differential Equation of a Distribution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

How to solve the differential equation in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R})$:

\begin{equation}
T''=\delta_a \Leftrightarrow \langle T'',\phi\rangle=\langle \delta_a,\phi''\rangle, \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})
\end{equation}

By now, I know how to solve the DE:
\begin{equation}
T'=\delta_a
\end{equation}

but how should I proceed for the other one?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean $T''(\phi)=\delta(\phi'')$. You know, that the "Heaviside function" is an integral of $\delta$, so what may be an integral of Heaviside?

Comment: @ Vobo Yes, thank you for your correction. Well, I think that I may have found the answer and that would be the distibution of the Ramp function. Would that be correct?